# A simple cipher that uses the sums of previous characters

Tags: python

I'm fairly happy with the code itself, but I'd like you to tear it apart.

```
def sumcipher(inpt, o=0, encrypt=True):
    if not isinstance(inpt, str):
        raise TypeError("Input must be a string")
    if encrypt:
        return ''.join([chr(((sum([ord(i) - 32 for i in inpt[j::-1]]) + (o % 96)) % 96) + 32) for j in range(len(inpt))])
    else:
        L = ""
        for i in range(len(inpt)):
            L += chr((((ord(inpt[i]) - 32) - sum([ord(j) - 32 for j in L])) % 96) + 32)
        return L
```

I'm mostly looking for ways to make it more elegant/simple.

PS: I'm very inexperienced with asking questions.

Comment: this is its take on the url of this question: `h, |#Gu T,u!-s1s|27e!m"(z3k%y-y~IU,~Bb$p.!u&%<"&{#|%yRLfv$#|yHV&'x}-;gty39h~r.:gt}Hf"x&:bwGc"s1s&&~:V%y1o"1q-!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with CRC, this doesn't offer cryptographic strength.

The `o` in the public API needs an informative name, perhaps "offset".

In a duck-typed language, feel free to omit checks such as:

```
if not isinstance(inpt, str):
    raise TypeError("Input nust be a string")
```

since the first call to `ord()` will have much the same effect. Do go to the trouble of writing a docstring which describes the arguments.

Rather than an `if`, you might break this into two functions.

Try to show parallel structure. You chose to build up a list of strings in the 1st case, yet appended to a string in the 2nd case.

One of your modulo operations, `(o % 96)`, seems to be redundant.

Consider naming your [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), 32 and 96. Or do away with them entirely: produce binary output which you then [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) encode.

The nested loops offer quadratic performance. You have an opportunity to store sums in a temp variable if you want linear performance.